# AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression order by UNIX timestamp

Tags: objective-c, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am new to NoSQL databases and I have changed my database schema from storing dates as a UTC timestamp string, to a UNIX timestamp (number), in hopes that I can create either a scan or a query expression to find the 1000 most recent items in the table. I have yet to find a simple snippet of code to accomplish this using the AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression class. Scan doesn't appear to have any sort mechanism but query might. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ORDER BY` functionality in DynamoDB. If you want to run a *top N* query you'll have to performa a scan and then order the results yourself.

Mark B is right that query results can be ordered by the sort key but that is only within the context of a query. Queries are inherently limited to a single partition key.

If your table is small then you can get away with creating a Global Secondary Index on the table in which the partition key can be an attribute that is the same for all items and then use the timestamp attribute as a sort key. But keep in mind that this will break down once your table gets bigger. And if you're doing that you might as well not be using Dynamo. You're better off with an relational database on RDS.

Comment: NoSQL sounds like the worst abomination ever created, thanks for helping me understand why

Comment: How to "Order By" in SQL land - Type "Order By [column name]". How to "Order By" in NoSQL DynamoDB - 1. Create a partition key 2. Create a sort key 3. Create a global secondary index including both keys 4. Ensure correct query permissions are set on global secondary index 5. Add keyConditionExpression for partition key 6. Pray to your God of choice 7. Spin around 3 times

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure the timestamp field is the sort key for your DynamoDB table (or the sort key for a Global Secondary Index on that table). Then you just need to run a query. From [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html):

> Query results are always sorted by the sort key value. If the data
>   type of the sort key is Number, the results are returned in numeric
>   order; otherwise, the results are returned in order of UTF-8 bytes. By
>   default, the sort order is ascending. To reverse the order, set the
>   ScanIndexForward parameter to false.